# Is there a word for the act of checking an id / passport?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am wondering if there is a word, or words, for the act of checking/validating a piece of identification, like a passport, or an id card?

An example would be the customs police officer sitting in the airport arrival section. When that person checks your passport, does that act have a more specific name than "checking", "verifying", or "validating" your passport?

Thanks!

Comment: [OZDIC](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/passport) suggests only 'check' as being a relevant collocate.

Comment: [The UK government](https://identityassurance.blog.gov.uk/2014/10/10/introducing-the-document-checking-service/) uses the phrase: "to validate UK issued passports" in reference to remote verification by certain companies.

Comment: I guess for the airport example specifically, you could use "passport control", but checking sounds pretty natural.

Answer (score 1):

Passport [**verification**](https://websites.usc.edu/sa/Passport-Verification-PPV/) seems valid.

> All new students are required to complete Passport Verification (PPV) with the Office of International Services (OIS) upon arrival to the U.S.
>
> [Verification](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verification) ~ (*mass noun*) 1. The process of establishing the truth, accuracy, or validity of something.
>
> ‘the *verification* of official documents’

Comment: OP mentioned verify.